# Onmouse event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseleave

Goodmorning,

ive a code that show an information box over a div with a background image and when the mouse is entering that div. The information box is higher so it is showing more text but when te mouse is leaving the div it must go smaller. but sometimes the mouse leave event is not working.

```js
$(".extra-info-vak, .extra-info-text").on('mouseenter', function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true).fadeOut({
        duration: 200,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true);
            $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({
                height: '150px'
            }, {
                duration: 800,
                queue: false,
                easing: 'easeOutQuart'
            });
        }
    });
})
$(".extra-info-vak").on('mouseleave', function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').animate({
        height: '60px'
    }, {
        duration: 800,
        queue: false,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        complete: function () {
            $(_this).find('.extra-info-text');
            $(_this).find('.triangle-up').fadeIn({
                duration: 200,
                queue: false
            });
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<section id="over">
<!-- Urenregistratie -->
<div class="row-fluid fixed over">
    <div class="span12">
         <h1 class="gray-text">Urenregistratie</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="extra-info-vak">
                <div class="triangle-up text-center"></div>
                <div class="extra-info-text orange">
                    <p class="text-center white-text ttl">Koptekst</p>
                    <p class="white-text">Hier komt tekst over dit onderdeel waar de muis overheen is gekomen</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="extra-info-vak">
                <div class="triangle-up text-center"></div>
                <div class="extra-info-text orange">
                    <p class="text-center white-text ttl">Koptekst</p>
                    <p class="white-text">Hier komt tekst over dit onderdeel waar de muis overheen is gekomen</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="extra-info-vak">
                <div class="triangle-up text-center"></div>
                <div class="extra-info-text orange">
                    <p class="text-center white-text ttl">Koptekst</p>
                    <p class="white-text">Hier komt tekst over dit onderdeel waar de muis overheen is gekomen</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your mouseenter event is assigned to both `.extra-info-vak` and `.extra-info-text`, yet the mouseleave is only on `.extra-info-vak`. Is that intentional?

Comment: it was a idea to solve the problem but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latest jQuery Hover method to avoid difficulties. Below is the high-level code that helps you.

```
$( ".extra-info-vak, .extra-info-text" ).hover(

   function() {
      // Mouseover Actions
   }, 
   function() {
     // Mouseout Actions
   }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kiran's suggestion should work for you. rest of them within your logic

**[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/0gafbb9m/2/)**

No **HTML** Changes same as Question

**CSS:**

```
.span4 { border:dashed 1px gold; margin:5px;}
.triangle-up {float:left;}
.triangle-up:before { content:"+"; color:orange;}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".extra-info-vak, .extra-info-text").hover(function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true);
    $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({
        height: '150px'
    }, {
        duration: 800,
        queue: false,
        easing: 'easeOutQuart',
        complete: function () {
            $(_this).find('.triangle-up').fadeOut({
                duration: 200,
                queue: false
            });
        }
    });
},

function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true);
    $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({
        height: '60px'
    }, {
        duration: 800,
        queue: false,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        complete: function () {
            $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true).fadeIn({
                duration: 200,
                queue: false
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

```
$( ".extra-info-vak, .extra-info-text" ).hover(
   function() {
        var _this = this;   

        $(this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true).fadeOut({
            duration:200,
            complete:function(){

                $(_this).addClass("open");
                $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true);

                $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({height:'150px'},{duration:800,queue:false,easing:'easeOutQuart'});

            }
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({height:'60px'},{
            duration:800,
            queue:false,
            easing:'easeOutBounce', 
            complete:function(){
                $(_this).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true);
                $(_this).find('.triangle-up').stop(true).fadeIn({duration:200, queue:false});
                $(_this).removeClass("open");
            }
        });
    }
);
$(".driekolom").on('mouseleave',function(){
    var openclasses = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
        $(openclasses).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true).animate({height:'60px'},{
            duration:800,
            queue:false,
            easing:'easeOutBounce', 
            complete:function(){
                $(openclasses).find('.extra-info-text').stop(true);
                $(openclasses).find('.triangle-up').stop(true).fadeIn({duration:200, queue:false});
                $(openclasses).removeClass("open");
            }
        });
});
```